# add expiration date to a node in Drupal

Tags: drupal, content-type, drupal-modules

i want to add an expiration date field to my custom content type in Drupal. it should specified by days (7-15-.... days after creating node) and after it reached the node should not display in site to visitors. but i need a renew option for it to allow creator renew it and activate it again.

is it too hard to impelmentation? how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you already tried searching for modules?

Here's one that might do the trick http://drupal.org/project/auto_expire. There are others as well,but maybe you should check them out to see which one fits your needs (or can be altered easily if needed).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Views to do that. Make a new View, specifically for a node or more nodes of that type, and put a filter on it with "Node:Updated". Then specify how many days you need.

You can create a View for the original poster and have him update the post, which will reset the counter.

A creative solution, but it should work.

Comment: thanks wouter but the expiration date is different to each node and the poster specify it so i can't put a static day value for it in views.it should get its value from another field of node.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Node expire](http://drupal.org/project/node_expire) which sets up timers for nodes based on [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules). For a simpler approach, [Scheduler](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler) can do it to. Both are linked from the [Auto Expire](http://drupal.org/project/auto_expire) module linked by wimvds, so there is some measure of duplication, though they do seem to have different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

The following code may be of interest. It's a small snippet from a module i've had to create to auto expire adverts on an intranet site. The nodes simply unpublish after a number of days you specify in the code so could be hidden from your site and then the author of the content could simply just re -publish the nodes if they needed to.

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_cron().
*/
function auto_unpublish_pages_cron() {

  //we only want to deal with all blog_post content type nodes
  $c_type = 'blog_post';

  //grab all nodes
  $c_nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $c_type));

  //setup time stamp for node expiry
  $message_search_data = strtotime('- 7 days'); 

  //now loop through nodes, & if they are old, expire them

  foreach ($c_nodes as $m) {
    $obj = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $m);

    //check when was last updated and if its still published
    $last_update = $obj->changed->value();

    $published = $obj->status->value();

    //if it's still published & it's not recent, unpublish it
    if (($message_search_date > $last_update) && $published<>0) {
      $obj->status = 0;
      $obj->save();

    }

  }   

}
```